# Finding length of continuous ones in list in a pyspark column

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to solve a problem in pyspark that includes collecting a list which contains only ones and zeros. I want to find the number of continuous ones in the list (after using collect_list).

```
# Sample data

sc = SparkContext().getOrCreate()
sqlCtx = SQLContext(sc)

json = [
    {'a': 'tank', 'b': 1},
    {'a': 'tank', 'b': 1}, {'a': 'bank', 'b': 1},
    {'a': 'tank', 'b': 0}, {'a': 'bank', 'b': 0},
    {'a': 'tank', 'b': 1}, {'a': 'bank', 'b': 1},
    {'a': 'tank', 'b': 1}, {'a': 'bank', 'b': 1},
    {'a': 'tank', 'b': 1}, {'a': 'bank', 'b': 1},
    {'a': 'tank', 'b': 1}, {'a': 'bank', 'b': 1},
]

df = sqlCtx.read.json(sc.parallelize(json))
df.show()

# Data looks like 
+----+---+
|   a|  b|
+----+---+
|tank|  1|
|tank|  1|
|bank|  1|
|tank|  0|
|bank|  0|
|tank|  1|
|bank|  1|
|tank|  1|
|bank|  1|
|tank|  1|
|bank|  1|
|tank|  1|
|bank|  1|
+----+---+

df = df.groupBy('a').agg(F.collect_list('b').alias('b'))
# Output looks like
+----+---------------------+
|a   |b                    |
+----+---------------------+
|bank|[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]   |
|tank|[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]|
+----+---------------------+
```

I would like to calculate the max number of continuous ones in `collect_list(b)` and if possible get the index of the start and end. I've tried implementing several logic but I can't get it right.

Comment: What's your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Spark Version 2.1 and above

Here's one approach if you have Spark version 2.1 or above:

First use [`pyspark.sql.posexplode()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.posexplode) to explode the collected list along with the indices.

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df = df.select("a", f.posexplode("b").alias("pos", "b"))
```

Next use a Window function to create a column that will indicate if the current row's value is different than the previous row.

```python
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy("a").orderBy("pos")
df = df.select(
    "*", 
    (f.col("b") != f.lag(f.col("b"), default=0).over(w)).cast("int").alias("change")
)
df.show()
#+----+---+---+------+
#|   a|pos|  b|change|
#+----+---+---+------+
#|bank|  0|  1|     1|
#|bank|  1|  0|     1|
#|bank|  2|  1|     1|
#|bank|  3|  1|     0|
#|bank|  4|  1|     0|
#|bank|  5|  1|     0|
#|tank|  0|  1|     1|
#|tank|  1|  1|     0|
#|tank|  2|  0|     1|
#|tank|  3|  1|     1|
#|tank|  4|  1|     0|
#|tank|  5|  1|     0|
#|tank|  6|  1|     0|
#+----+---+---+------+
```

Compute the cumulative sum of that column to separate the `0`s and `1`s into groups. Then you can `groupBy()` the columns `(a, b, group)` and compute the length of each group as well as the start and end index.

```python
df = df.select(
    "*",
    f.sum(f.col("change")).over(w.rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)).alias("group")
)\
.groupBy("a", "b", "group")\
.agg(f.min("pos").alias("start"), f.max("pos").alias("end"), f.count("*").alias("length"))\
.where(f.col("b") == 1)\
.drop("group")
df.show()
#+----+---+-----+---+------+
#|   a|  b|start|end|length|
#+----+---+-----+---+------+
#|bank|  1|    0|  0|     1|
#|bank|  1|    2|  5|     4|
#|tank|  1|    0|  1|     2|
#|tank|  1|    3|  6|     4|
#+----+---+-----+---+------+
```

Finally you can filter this DataFrame to find the row associated with the longest length sequence for each item in column `a`:

```python
df = df.withColumn(
    "isMax",
    f.col("length") == f.max(f.col("length")).over(Window.partitionBy("a"))
)\
.where(f.col("isMax"))\
.drop("isMax")
df.show()
#+----+---+-----+---+------+
#|   a|  b|start|end|length|
#+----+---+-----+---+------+
#|bank|  1|    2|  5|     4|
#|tank|  1|    3|  6|     4|
#+----+---+-----+---+------+
```

---

#### Spark Version 1.5 and above

If you don't have `posexplode`, another option is to cast your array of integers into an array of strings, concatenate it, and split on `"0"`. Then explode the resultant array, and filter for the one with the max length.

Unfortunately, this approach does not give you the start and end positions.

```python
df.withColumn('b', f.split(f.concat_ws('', f.col('b').cast('array<string>')), '0'))\
    .select('a', f.explode('b').alias('b'))\
    .select('a', f.length('b').alias('length'))\
    .withColumn(
        "isMax",
        f.col('length') == f.max(f.col('length')).over(Window.partitionBy('a'))
    )\
    .where(f.col("isMax"))\
    .drop("isMax")\
    .show()
#+----+------+
#|   a|length|
#+----+------+
#|bank|     4|
#|tank|     4|
#+----+------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. the start and end is what I need. I am using pyspark package 2.3, and getting an error on this line `df = df.select("*", (F.col("b") != F.lag(F.col("b"), default=0).over(w)).cast("int").alias("change"))
`

Comment: `py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o98.showString.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: @pissall that is weird. I'm using 2.1 currently - maybe it had an issue with the `default` parameter? I put that in to avoid the `null`, but there's a way around it.